# config Orbeon form and MySQL

Tags: mysql, configure, orbeon

how I can configure Orbeon forms and MySQL, and try almost everything and seen on the internet, I would like someone to help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: For anyone wondering what Orbeon Forms are: http://www.orbeon.com/forms/documentation

Comment: Do you have Orbeon installed properly, what server are you using, Tomcat, WebSphere, JBoss, etc?  Also have you read through this: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/mysql-persistence-layer

Comment: I'm using apache/tomcat y windows

Comment: You haven't answered @Orbling's last question: did you check that wiki entry: "MySQL Persistence Layer"?

Answer (score 1):

See [MySQL Persistence Layer](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/mysql-persistence-layer) for more information on how to setup Orbeon Forms with MySQL.

(And if after doing this you're still having problems, please update your question to include more details on the problem you are seeing, and also post a comment on this response, so we get a notification from Stack Overflow that you did update the question.)